# DataGrid для одновременного ввода и отображения данных

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Хочу организовать удобный способ ввода данных, да никак не разберусь.

Имеются данные о книгах в `DataSet` в виде таблицы. Каждой книге присвоен ID.

Нужен особый `DataGrid`. Пользователь может добавлять новые строки. В первый столбец вводится ID и обрабатывается - остальные столбцы строки заполняются данными по книге с указанным ID (если такая есть). При этом остальные столбцы должны быть нередактируемыми.

Как описать такую таблицу и какое событие следует ловить, чтобы отследить введённый ID?

Comment: Думаю для вашей задачи корректнее сделать форму для ввода, а грид только для отображения.

Comment: Отличная мысль. Так и сделаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос оставлю на всякий случай.

Comment: А чем не подходит DataGridView?

Comment: Не уверен, что он есть в  WPF.